# can't get through validation of nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have one model Biblio and one model Authors. They are habtm in relation to each other.

Adding a new biblio, I have a nested form. I do that like so:

```
<%= form_for :biblio, url: administration_add_biblio_path do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :authors, Author.new do |aut| %>
        <%= aut.hidden_field :name , :name =>"biblio[authors][1]" %>
    <% end %>
```

This is part of the params that are sent to the controller :

```
"biblio"=>{"authors"=>{"1"=>{"name"=>"Vabien"}}, "title"=>"test",....
```

In biblios_controller, I have this :

```
def params_biblio
    params.require(:biblio).permit(
         :authors)
```

which has this problem: `Unpermitted parameter: authors`

the model Biblio looks like this:

```
class Biblio < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
    validates_presence_of :authors
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
    validates_associated :authors
```

and class author:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord

    has_and_belongs_to_many :biblios
    validates :given_name, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true
```

The problem is that this validation of author always fails. I guess this is due to the fact that `[:author][:name]`is passed to Author model - but I'm not sure that that's the problem and if so how to solve it.

I should add that the biblio can have a whole bunch of authors, but only the presence of author["1"] needs to be validated.

Comment: Is this a typo? `auteurs` for `authors`

Comment: yes type, I corrected it as you made that comment. Forgot to translate from french to english. Now done.

Comment: Did you create the authors_biblios table?  Make sure the table is Authors_Biblios and not the other way around.  Rails expects tables such as these to be named in lexical order.

Comment: @bkunzi01: yes I did that (and without the validation code, that table gets populated correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Nested strong parameters are a bit tricky in this sense. You have to define your nested parameters to make this work. So try this:

```
params.require(:biblio).permit(authors: :name)
```

Or with other params:

```
params.require(:biblio).permit(:title, authors: :name)
```

Comment: When I do that, I get `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Administration::BibliosController#create` and `Author(#70213626064300) expected, got Array(#70213521745920)`  (Author singular that is). I don't have the unpermitted parameter error any more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the "1" key in your object being passed back to the controller. Would it make more sense to pass the authors back as an array rather than an object.

```
"biblio"=>{"authors"=>[{"name"=>"Vabien"}], "title"=>"test",....
```

Comment: How do I do that? I currently have this in my form: `<%= aut.text_field :name , :name =>"biblio[authors][name]"` and that results in an object.

Comment: try:    <%= aut.text_feild :name, :name=>"biblio[authors][][name]"